# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON LIKE CONCAT Wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database containing different information from our website.  One table (called Raw_Pages) contains a list of every page on our site and the path to it (along with other fields of course).  Another table (called Paths) contains a list of various branches of the site that are owned by different departments.

I'm trying to run a query to basically find all pages on the site that do not fall under one of the branches specified.

```sql
table Raw_Pages
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Field                   | Type         |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| ID                      | int(11)      |
| Path                    | varchar(500) |
| Title                   | varchar(255) |
+-------------------------+--------------+

table Paths
+----------+--------------+
| Field    | Type         |
+----------+--------------+
| ID       | int(11)      |
| Path     | varchar(255) |
+----------+--------------+
```

We currently have 64,002 pages I'm checking against 757 paths (All departments have multiple branches due to different ones for different file types).  I'm also planning to do a similar query for files, of which we have 306,625 and pulls from the same list of 757 paths.  Yes, our site is a giant mess.

From what I can tell, a LEFT JOIN is what would work best for me with a wildcard on the right side.  I am a novice at code so I could be far off.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Raw_Pages LEFT JOIN Paths ON Raw_Pages.path LIKE CONCAT(Paths.Path,'%') WHERE Paths.ID IS NULL
```

I'm honestly not sure if the above code works or not since it just freezes phpMyAdmin when I try it.  I'm assuming something is wrong in it, or there is a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on `Paths(Path)`, you might be able to do:

```
select rp.*
from raw_pages rp
where not exists (select 1
                  from paths p
                  where p.path <= rp.path and
                        p.path > concat(rp.path, '(')
                 );
```

It is possible for the subquery to use an index.  I'm not sure it will.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the **path** field is identical in the two tables you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Raw_Pages AS R
LEFT JOIN Paths AS P ON (R.path=P.path)
WHERE R.ID IS NULL
```

If it matches only the name of the page or a piece of the route

```
SELECT * 
FROM Raw_Pages AS R
LEFT JOIN Paths AS P ON (R.path LIKE CONCAT('%',P.path,'%'))
WHERE R.ID IS NULL
```

[You can check this page to verify the type of query you need](https://www.genbeta.com/desarrollo/explicacion-grafica-de-los-join-en-sql-y-sus-resultados)

It is good practice to index the **path** fields in both tables so that the query is faster due to the number of records